# Difference between AddLocal and AddSource?

Tags: deployment, windows-installer

When you install your product locally, all the needed files are stored in the machine.

When you set the features to Advertise, files will be installed locally when the user launches the application.

What happens then when yo set the features to "run-from-source"? I Googled it and was only able to find this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rarely used feature of Windows Installer and I don't normally reccomend using it.  It was invented back in a day when hard drives were small and the thought was you 'advertised' ( pretend install aka install source ) a feature and that when the user clicks the shortcut it would go to the source and finish the installation of the feature ( aka install local )

It just adds a lot of complexity to your servicing model. It's not worth it IMO.

Comment: Same thoughts here Chris. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When placing all installation files next to the MSI (similar to advertised installation), you can install features from source. This means that all files in these features will be used from the MSI location (they are not copied in the target folders during install).

Running from source can be used when the installer remains permanently on the target machine. So the application can use the installer directly instead of using installed files.